# How buildEnv builtin function works?

Tags: nix, nixpkgs

How [buildEnv](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/master/corepkgs/buildenv.nix) works? Why its builtin? How can I use it? [What does `manifest` argument?](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/master/corepkgs/buildenv.nix#L1) Where is the documentation about buildEnv?

Comment: One buildEnv is mentioned in the nixpkgs manual chapter "2.7. Declarative Package Management":
https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#sec-declarative-package-management

The chapter is hard to understand without an understanding what this buildEnv function does and what its arguments are.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are looking the actual `buildenv.nix` or the `buildEnv` function?

Because `buildenv.nix` is an internal mechanism of the Nix package manager not of much interest for non developer of Nix itself.

If you're interested in the `buildEnv` function is part of [NixPkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs) package collection, this function is implemented here: 
https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/build-support/buildenv/default.nix

Even if the code give some hints, I didn't found any real documentation, but you can find some examples in the manual:
 https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-building-environment

If I understand correctly, the manifest is also internal to Nix: It is a Nix file that contains a list of derivation that correspond to a given environment. You can have a look at one on a machine with nix in `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/manifest.nix` for example.

It is not very readable, it looks like this:

`[ { meta = { }; name = "nixos-18.09pre143771.a8c71037e04"; out = { outPath = "/nix/store/yqxc408mhbcksnaqndkpdkg8ylcj2xhg-nixos-18.09pre143771.a8c71037e04"; }; outPath = "/nix/store/yqxc408mhbcksnaqndkpdkg8ylcj2xhg-nixos-18.09pre143771.a8c71037e04"; outputs = [ "out" ]; system = "x86_64-linux"; type = "derivation"; } { meta = { }; name = "nixos-1803-18.03.132768.94d80eb7247"; out = { outPath = "/nix/store/ih8bhvgmp47rs3acchkc9ch7f8760rpz-nixos-1803-18.03.132768.94d80eb7247"; }; outPath = "/nix/store/ih8bhvgmp47rs3acchkc9ch7f8760rpz-nixos-1803-18.03.132768.94d80eb7247"; outputs = [ "out" ]; system = "x86_64-linux"; type = "derivation"; } ]`

Comment: are `builtins.buildenv` and `lib.buildEnv` do same thing?

Comment: The nixpkgs buildEnv is used quite a lot to compose environments together. Often to create really simple proxy environments that wrap an existing package in some sort of configuration. For example by adding an option or flag to an existing package's binary.

Comment: Shouldn't `buildEnv` be documented in Nixpkgs manual under [Chapter 7. Functions reference](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#chap-functions)? It seems that most of the sections there describe packages in `nixpkgs/pkgs/build-support/` (where `buildEnv` resides as well).